# MVC application: json + view output

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I developed an mvc-razor app the classical way: I do some computation in my controller and show the results in the view.

Now, in addition to the formatted output I already provide through the view,  I need to add the ability to provide the same results in json, so that my controller acts as a service.

Something like

```
if (json == true)
{    
    return JsonOutput(model);
}
else
{
    return View(model);
}
```

Since I don't want to reinvent the wheel, I wonder if there is a standard approach to this task.

Thank you

Comment: Are you using asp.net core or the full framework?

Comment: Full framework.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is an ApiController:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class EmployeesController : ControllerBase { ... }
```

In this controller you will define your action methods, very much like in Mvc, but not return a View:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get() 
{
   /* ... retrieve results*/
   return Ok(yourPayload);
}
```

I suggest you follow along the excellent documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Thank you Marco, in my question I didn't stress that I need BOTH functionalities: view AND json. I'll update the question to better clarify this.

Comment: Having both possibilities in one method is not possible. It is possible to return Json from the same controller, though. However I would advise to have seperate controllers, for SOLID reasons. But if you want, I could give you an updated answer with the alternative solution.